# Combining FastAPI and application with multiples options

Tags: python, fastapi

I have created an application that given a DNA sequence (string) does some manipulation.

I want to Build Python Web APIs to incorporate this.

The application has a few tools so I want to allow the user to select the desired tool and after being given de input get the output. For example with the tool length

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/length?input=TATA

{
    "result":4
}
```

What makes (for me) complicated is that I have this application created in many scripts and main.py script to give input and return output.

This is part of my main.py script

```
import sys
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from clases.read_file import Read_file
import argparse
from fastapi import FastAPI
 
app = FastAPI()
 
@app.get("/DNA_toolkit")
def sum(input_sequence):
    return {"Result": ????? }



user_input = sys.argv[1] # This was the input in the application when working with the command line

DNA = Sequence(user_input) # and this took the input but now I don't know how to manage the input when working with API 

# print(DNA.load_data())
print("Length:")
print(DNA.length())
print("\n")
```

Comment: Your web application now runs on its own, and accepts input over HTTP. So you need to remove the CLI arguments completely and instead you'd provide them via an HTTP **client** (such as cURL or Postman). This doesn't really have anything to do with Python/FastAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to get what you need. For example, you can exploit path and query parameters.

If you want to query your API like http://127.0.0.1:8000/DNA_toolkit/?query=TATA, you need a query param. Your code would look like this:

```
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from fastapi import FastAPI
 
app = FastAPI()
 
@app.get("/DNA_toolkit")
def sum(query: str): # pass the sequence in, this time as a query param
    DNA = Sequence(query) # get the result (i.e., 4)
    return {"Result": DNA.length() } # return the response
```

Another simple design choice could be mapping API paths to tools (e.g., `DNA_toolkit`) and using path parameters to pass in your very dynamic data (e.g., `TATA`).

Your code would look like the following

```
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from fastapi import FastAPI
 
app = FastAPI()
 
@app.get("/DNA_toolkit/{sequence: str}") # this endpoint expects a DNA Sequence (a string)
def sum(sequence): # pass the sequence to your path operation function
    DNA = Sequence(sequence) # get the result (i.e., 4)
    return {"Result": DNA.length() } # return the response
```

That's it. Now call http://127.0.0.1:8000/DNA_toolkit/TATA and you are done!

Comment: I am the same user that that one who put the question (I can't comment with my new account) I have added DNA.length() in the last DNA and then that works. Thanks!!

Comment: If I have more than one tool (eg. length, convert...) how can I allow the user to use the one they want?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, you are right. Just to expand this topic, you can definitely use `input` as a function param and your code still works. As a side effect, you overwrites `<built-in function input>` with a string in the function scope. This is not a big deal here, since your are in a Web context, and you aren't probably going to deal with standard output.  But you are right, naming is important. Thank you for your attention to details.

Comment: @ManuelDominguezBecerra, happy if this helped. Regarding your question, you just need to create more endpoints with relative path operation functions. Check out the FastAPI doc for more.

Comment: PS: the same issue with built-in naming collisions holds for the function `sum`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of poeple who answer my question I have copies and expanded the code.

```
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from clases.read_file import Read_file
from fastapi import FastAPI
 
app = FastAPI()
 
@app.get("/DNA_toolkit")
def sum(input: str):                        # pass the sequence in, this time as a query param
    DNA = Sequence(input)                         # get the result (i.e., 4)
    return {"Length": DNA.length(),         # return the response
            "Reverse": DNA.reverse(),
            "complement":DNA.complement(),
            "Reverse and complement": DNA.reverse_and_complement(),
            "gc_percentage": DNA.gc_percentage()
            }
```

Comment: Best not to use `sum` and `input` as function names or params. Also, what are all these extra JSON values you are returning?